# LinkButton Command event handler args always strings

Tags: asp.net

I've got a LinkButton control in a user control like this (Accordion is from the AJAX Control Toolkit):

```
<cc1:Accordion runat="server">
    <Panes></Panes>
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Update" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>' CommandName="ItemUpdate" OnCommand="LinkButton_Command" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
</cc1:Accordion>
```

The accordion is bound in Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Accordion1.DataSource = GetACollection();
    Accordion1.DataBind();
}
```

But in the command event handler, no matter what I do, the arguments are always strings:

```
protected void LinkButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
      // sender is alway a string (the Text of the clicked button)
      // e is always a string property of the Container.DataItem object
}
```

The strings are coming from the right objects (the button and the bound DataItem, respectively), but I need the objects themselves (the DataItem particularly).

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't that be expected behavior..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx

> **Property Value** Type: System..::.String
>   An optional argument passed to the
>   Command event handler along with the
>   associated CommandName property. The
>   default value is String..::.Empty.

Comment: doh!  you're right.  The debugger made me think I could pass objects, but you're right.  The property only accepts strings.