# The problemis that the button's OnClick works just fine in updating the database but using LinkButton has no effect

Tags: asp.net, database, button, onclick, linkbutton

//LinkButton definition in aspx page

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkUpdate" runat="server" OnClick="linkUpdate_Click">Update </asp:LinkButton>
```

//linkUpdate_Click - the action i want to get executed when the linkbutton is clicked

```
protected void linkUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   string DeptName = txtName.Text;
   string Profile = txtProfile.Text;

   string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
       string sql = "update Sectors set DeptName = '" + txtName.Text + "',Profile='" + txtProfile.Text + "' where DeptID =1";
       connection.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       Response.Redirect("Architecture.aspx");
       connection.Close();
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:linkbutton id="linkUpdate" runat="server" 
    text="Login" onclick="linkUpdate_Click"></asp:linkbutton>
```

check **onclick="linkUpdate_Click"** event in your link button

Just check below links

[dynamic LinkButton OnClick event not working on ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106715/dynamic-linkbutton-onclick-event-not-working-on-asp-net)

[LinkButton Command event handler args always strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735581/linkbutton-command-event-handler-args-always-strings)